# Android load a specific fragment when app resumes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got an app with an Activity and several fragments.
One of the fragment is a login fragment where a user types his password in order to continue.

How can I acheive that the user:

1) Won't be able to backpress and get to that fragment after a succesful login.

2) When the app is resuming and coming back to the foreground, that this fragment will load and ask the user again for his password.

Comment: So you want to force user to login even if he use Home button to exit from your app?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but perhaps yes. The first requirement is more important right now.

Comment: Have you tried closing the activity after calling the login one ? And simply reset the login flag after the user exits from the app by pressing home key or back key.

Comment: how do I close the activity? If i do that, will the app remain in the list of open apps in the background? and will the activity automatically reload when the user tries to reload it again?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on that if your application is using only one `MainActivity` and `Fragments` or has many `Activities` and `Fragments` the solution will be different, but assume that you have one `Activity` and lots of other `Fragments` the easiest way will be after successful login, just don't add your `LoginFragment` to your app's `Fragment` history (backStack).
And in your `MainActivity's` `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` you should logOut your current user and make him login again after he opens your `MainActivity` .

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: Not sure I understand how to do this part: "And in your MainActivity's onPause() or onDestroy() you should log your current user and make him login again after he opens your MainActivity ."

Comment: That depends on your code, how you logout your user?

Answer (score 0):

use static variable to perform conditional operations

for e.g

static int x=0;

in yout activity  onResume  or in onCreate as you want to manage

```
      if(x==0)
      {
          x=1;
          your fragment 1
      }
     else if(x==1)
     {     x=0;
          your fragment 2
     }
```

and you are done.